# Prove that estimator isn't consistent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider $X_1 \ldots X_n \sim N(\theta, 1)$ are i.r.v. Let's consider $\tau = \mathbb{P}(X_1 > 0)$. We want to find MLE estimator of $\tau$ and then do the following. Suppose that $X_1 \ldots X_n$ are not normally distributed, then we need to show that estimator isn't consistent.

My try:

I've proved that $\hat{\tau}_{MLE} = 1 - \Phi(-\bar{X})$. Now let's focus on the second part.
First of all, I suppose that we still consider the same estimator $\hat{\tau}_{MLE}$. Then if it's so why don't we have consistency? I mean, because of $-\bar{X} \xrightarrow{P} -\mathbb{E}(X)$ and because of $\Phi(x)$ is continuous function we should have $\hat{\tau}_{MLE} \xrightarrow{P} 1 - \Phi(-\mathbb{E}(X))$. Maybe I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(x)=\frac{1}{C(x^4+1)}$ where $C=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+1}$. Take a SRS $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim f$ and put $\bar{X}_n=\frac{X_1+\dots +X_n}{n}$.

By the weak law of a large numbers we have $\bar{X}_n\rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X_1)=0$ in probability. Therefore $1-\Phi(-\bar{X}_n)\rightarrow 1-\Phi(-0)=1/2$ in probability as well. But $1/2=P(X_1>0)$ so $1-\Phi(-\bar{X_n})$ is a consistent estimator for $P(X_1>0)$ even though $X_1$ isn't normal.

Comment: I also feel that it might be consistent.